# onActivityResult doesn't work in fragment tab

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter, android-fragmentactivity

I have a fragment tab using a listView. Each row of listview (arrayAdapter) have a picture button, and i set button click event like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vehiclereservationdocument_list, parent, false);
    }

    VehicleReservationDocument vrDocument = getItem(position);

    Button btnTakePicture = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btnTakePicture);
    btnTakePicture.setTag(R.id.WOP_POSITION, position);
    btnTakePicture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            takePicture((Integer) view.getTag(R.id.WOP_POSITION));
        }
    });

    btnTakePicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    return row;
}

public void takePicture(int position) {
    // Ação do botão

    documentStrategy = DocumentStrategy.PICTURE;
    VehicleReservationDocument vrd = vehicleReservationDocuments.get(position);
    this.argDocument = position;

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(vrd.getVehicleReservation());

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    VehicleReservationTabFragment.fragmentWhoCalledStartActivityForResult = VehicleReservationTabFragment.VehicleReservationTabFragmentGroupId.TAB_VEHICLERESERVATION_DOCUMENT.ordinal();
    TabVehicleReservationDocumentFragment.setFileUri(fileUri);
    TabVehicleReservationDocumentFragment.setArgDocument(argDocument);

    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, documentStrategy.ordinal());
}
```

ActivityResult in my tabFragment:

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        ACTION _actionOrigin = TabVehicleReservationDocumentFragment._actionOrigin;

        UploadDocument uploadDocument = new UploadDocument(getActivity(), _actionOrigin);
        uploadDocument.execute();
}
```

After taking the photo, I need to go to onActivityResult, but it doesn't work, the event is not called. Any one can help me? Thanks!!!

Comment: Override onActivityResult() in your parent activity

Comment: i tried, but dont works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set your adapter then do something like this hope this will help you.

```
YourAdapter adapter = new YourAdapter(do your stuff, clickListener);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);


Define this method in your Activity

View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        documentStrategy = DocumentStrategy.PICTURE;
        VehicleReservationDocument vrd = vehicleReservationDocuments.get(position);
        this.argDocument = position;

        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(vrd.getVehicleReservation());

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        VehicleReservationTabFragment.fragmentWhoCalledStartActivityForResult = VehicleReservationTabFragment.VehicleReservationTabFragmentGroupId.TAB_VEHICLERESERVATION_DOCUMENT.ordinal();
        TabVehicleReservationDocumentFragment.setFileUri(fileUri);
        TabVehicleReservationDocumentFragment.setArgDocument(argDocument);

        startActivityForResult(intent, documentStrategy.ordinal());
    }
};

**Your Adapterclass**

public class YourAdapter extend BaseAdapter {
    private View.onClickListener clickListener;

    public YourAdapter(your stuff, View.onClickListener clickListener) {
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.vehiclereservationdocument_list, parent, false);
        }

        VehicleReservationDocument vrDocument = getItem(position);


        Button btnTakePicture = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.btnTakePicture);
        btnTakePicture.setTag(R.id.WOP_POSITION, position);
        btnTakePicture.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

        btnTakePicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        return row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use startActivityForResult without context

```
startActivityForResult(intent, documentStrategy.ordinal());
```

Comment: It is not possible because the process is being called from the arrayadapter class

Answer (score 0):

Move your **takePicture** method in fragment class. and use

```
startActivityForResult(intent, documentStrategy.ordinal());
```

instead of

```
((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, documentStrategy.ordinal());
```

First method callbacks fragments onActivityResult where, second callbacks activity's onActivityResult

Comment: The problem is that the button is in my arrayAdapter, and I can not access the same from my fragment, so I'm using the takepicture method by the arrayAdapter class.

Comment: You can implement listener and access that method from fragment

Answer (score 0):

To get the result in your fragment make sure you call startActivityForResult(intent,111); instead of getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,111); inside your fragment.

Comment: i sure about that! but dosent works... Strange right?